# Custom DOM elements (Icons, CSS) removed whenever a new email received in Gmail

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I have an assignment to change Gmail Inbox's rows UI and add the icons to make it look better, but whenever I am adding through DOM using javascript, it is shown.

[image: Gmail UI Enhancement]

But when the new email is received, the DOM disappears my current CSS and the icons from all the rows(I have highlighted with red colour). Google refreshes the complete table whenever I received a new email, and my current changes remove from the DOM.

Is there any way the changes does not disappear in the DOM whenever Gmail reload?

**Updated**

Whenever a new email reaches I am able to add changes to that row due to the Mutation observer observing that a node with TR is added. But the issue is that whenever a new email arrives Gmail replaces a chunk of 5-10 rows and removes all my changes and I am unable to catch that change made in the DOM.

```
    function getChildrenById(node, id) {
    for (const child of node.children) {
        if(child.id === id) {
            return child;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
function onMutation(mutations) {
    const found = [];
    for (const { removedNodes } of mutations) {
        for (const node of removedNodes) {
            if (!node.tagName) continue; // not an element
            // debugger
            if (node.tagName === 'TR') {
                console.log(node);
                debugger
                if (node.getElementsByClassName("yX xY") && !getChildrenById(node, 'place_icon')){
                    node.getElementsByClassName("yX xY")[0].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div id='place_icon'>hello&nbsp;</div>");
                }
            }
            if (node.id === 'place_icon') {
                debugger
            }
            if (node.classList.contains('yX') && node.classList.contains('xY')) {
                node.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div id='place_icon'>hello&nbsp;</div>");
                console.log(node);
            }
        }
    }
}
tableDivContainer = $('.BltHke.nH.oy8Mbf.aE3.S4');
const observer = new MutationObserver(onMutation);
observer.observe(tableDivContainer, {
    childList: true,
    attributes: true,
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributeOldValue: true,
    characterDataOldValue: true
});
```

Comment: Use the javascript MutationObserver API

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I have updated the question with the MutationObserver please check and let me know. Thank You

Comment: Sounds like **part** of the page reloads and you don't have the MutationObserver **high** enough on the page. If your MO is on Elements that gets removed; the MO **is** removed. Put a MutationObserver on ``document`` and see what happens